# Powershell code raising error while adding contribute permission on term group to everyone

Tags: powershell

```
Add-PSSnapin "microsoft.sharepoint.powershell"
#Connect to the Metadata Service
$taxSite = get-SPSite "CentralAdminURL"    # Central Admin URL   
$taxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -site $taxSite
$termStore = $taxonomySession.TermStores["MetadataServiceName"] # Meta data service name
#Create a group
$termGroup = $termstore.CreateGroup("NewTermGroup") # New group 
$termStore.CommitAll()

#Connect to existing term group
$termGroup = $termstore.groups["NewTermGroup"];

#TERM SETS
#Create a term set
$termSet = $termGroup.CreateTermSet(“Skills”)
$termStore.CommitAll()

#Connect to existing term set
$termset = $TermGroup.Termsets["Skills"]

#Adding a default term to term set
$term = $termSet.CreateTerm("Sea wall",1033)
$term.SetDescription(“Sea wall”, 1033)
$term.CreateLabel("Seawall”, 1033, $false)

$TermSet.IsOpenForTermCreation = $true;

# Contribute permission on term group (This statement raising error)
$user = "c:0(.s|true"
$termGroup.AddContributor($user)

# Contribute permission on term group   (This statement raising error)
#$termGroup.AddContributor(“Domain\\Everyone”)

$termStore.CommitAll()
```

**Error:**

> Exception calling "AddContributor" with "1" argument(s): "The user name 'ec\everyone' can not be found.
>   Parameter name: principalName"
>   At line:11 char:1
>   + $termGroup.AddContributor("Domain\everyone")
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

Comment: Is this 2010 or 2013? What type of authentication do you use? The "Everyone" loginname differs depending on those two factors

Comment: We are using windows authentication.Requirement is by using custom user profile property every user can add a term to term set.

Comment: Is it 2010 or 2013?

Comment: yes it is in 2013.

Comment: So it is claim to windows you are using? The way we get the "Everyone" user in code is `web.EnsureUser("c:0(.s|true");` where "c:0(.s|true" actually is the claims token for "All users"

Comment: Hi Robert, Please let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: Well you probably have the solution in my last comment.. you should put in "c:0(.s|true" instead of "Domain\\Everyone". But an easier solution would probably be to mark the termset at Open?

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from the argument passed with AddContributor.  The string to be passed should be the login name of a user, not a path.  Cycle through the actual users of your site, and add each user individually to the term group.

Here are some references to take a look at to understand it better.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.group.addcontributor%28v=office.14%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/3w1b3114

Answer (score 1):

The second one that raises error can be solved by removing the escape character: "\", because it causes an error in PowerShell. So here is the working code:

```
$termGroup.AddContributor("Domain\Everyone")
```